# Почему не получается создать тхт файл на рабочем столе?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class createTextFile
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter digit: ");
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc1.nextInt();
        digits(a);
    }

    public static void digits(int a)
    {
        switch (a)
        {
        case 1:
            try
            {
                String computername = System.getProperty("user.name");
                File file = new File("C:\\Users\\+computername +\\Desktop\\file.txt");
                // PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter("file.txt");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

ввожу число 1 и ничего!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String fileName = System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\Desktop\\file.txt";
File file = new File(fileName);
try {           
    file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо содержимого переменной, Вы пишите ее название, потому что забыли выделить ее скобками.

Вместо этого:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\+computername +\\Desktop\\file.txt");
```

Нужно написать это:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\" + computername + "\\Desktop\\file.txt");
```

**UPD_0:** вот чтобы не угадывать, почему что не работает, нужно обрабатывать исключения. У меня подозрение на то, что у программы просто нет разрешений и Вам выбрасывается `IOException`, который вы игнорируете.

Сделайте так:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**UPD_1**: да и вообще, для создания файла, нужно его создать (как я сразу не заметил...). После `File file = new File(..);` напишите следующую строку:

```
Files.createFile(Paths.get(file.getPath()));
```

Это создаст Вам файл. А если не сможет создать - выбросит ошибку, где будет написано из-за чего.

Comment: все равно не вижу тхт на рабочем столе, что не так та ? не понимаю(((

Comment: подчёркивает это слово `IOException` сверху есть `import java.io.IOException;`

Comment: @glonval, еще раз обновил.

Comment: создался ...:-)